# Update parent table column only if all the values of child table rows are a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, orders and order_items. Each order can have multiple order_items.

An order has an `id` and `orderStatus`:

[image]

An order_item as `id`, `orderId` and `orderItemStatus`:
[image]

I want to update the `status` of order's from `OPEN` to `FULFILLED` if all an order's order_items have `status` of `ISSUED`. If at least one order_item is not `ISSUED`, the order `status` should remain as `OPEN`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS subquery as condition.

```
update order o
set o.orderStatus = 'FULFILLED'
where o.orderStatus = 'OPEN'
  and not exists (
    select *
    from order_item i
    where i.orderId = o.id
      and i.orderItemStatus <> 'ISSUED'
  )
```

This will only update orders which have status 'OPEN' and have no items with status 'ISSUED'.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel in the sub-query, should that be 'ACCEPTED' rather than 'ISSUED'?

Comment: @Mark I've misread your question, and now changed to `<> 'ISSUED'`. This is now equivalent to: "If at least one order_item is not ISSUED, the order status should remain as OPEN"

Comment: @Parfait Since the SELECT clause in (NOT) EXISTS subqueries is irrelevant and therefor is ignored by the engine - Everyone is using what they like. I for my part don't like to write something that looks meaningful, but is not. So I stick with `SELECT *`. The same applies for `COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for orders_item with status ISSUED if this is the unique status

```
    update orders o
    inner join (
      select orderID, count( dictinct orderItemStatus)
      from order_item
      group by orderID
      having count( dictinct orderItemStatus) = 1
    )  t on t.orderID = o.id 
    inner join order_item i on i.orderID  = o.id 
      AND orderItemStatus  = 'ISSUED'
```